# How to format numbers in column so that they are aligned on decimal point (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have column of numbers as follows:

```
   45.56
   132.43
   5
   3.4
```

I need it to look like this:

```
    45.56
   132.43
     5
     3.4
```

How do I do that in HTML/CSS? Is it even possible?

Comment: In straight HTML/CSS? I doubt it. You'd likely need JS or some kind of pre-processor (PHP for example) to apply some `&nbsp;` padding on the left/right based off of the longest value.

Comment: Or, cut each of the numbers in three parts and use a CSS table with three columns.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use only straight css/html without js.

Comment: @MrLister, could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of (with a bit of cheating) is close to the approach @Mr Lister mentioned in his comment, but without actual tables (e.g. using css properties to set the table display). Regardless, you need to modify/create the markup accordingly on the server-side (or with JS) and of course you'll create semantic/accessibility issues while doing so with either approach as the numbers are split up into pieces, so I would actually recommend @Tim Lewis approach to left/right pad the numbers with `&nbsp;`'s as it will leave the numbers intact...but for that you need some kind of scripting language client or server side!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*font-family: monospace; /* recommended */
  text-align: right;
}
.wrapper span {
  display: table-row;
}
[data-before]:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  display: table-cell;
}
[data-after]:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span data-before="45" data-after=".56" aria-label="45.56"></span>
  <span data-before="132" data-after=".42" aria-label="132.42"></span>
  <span data-before="5" data-after="" aria-label="5"></span>
  <span data-before="3" data-after=".4" aria-label="3.4"></span>
  <span data-before="12001" data-after=".40140101" aria-label="12001.40140101"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Exo font, I don't think it's monospace.

Comment: @user3151858 changed the example to use sans-serif font, no visible difference so far, but there is of course a risk of having that depending on your font if it is not monospace, single characters can have varying widths which might cause misalignment, but I assume with the more common ones you might get lucky =)!

Comment: This is a much smarter approach than I had in mind!

Comment: @Mr Lister thanks =), was inspired by you though, so thank you!